# How to use Vault dynamic secretes and inject them as Environment Variables to Kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

We run a Vault cluster (Deployed by helm) and some microservices all on k8s.
Our MongoDB atlas connection string configured as ENV on microservices deployment.
We want to continue using ENV without changing the code to read the vault config file. So, we tried the examples from here:

https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/injector/examples

The injection to ENV works but when the vault rotates the credentials we need to recreate the pod that it will inject again to the ENV.

I would like to know How we may use the functionality of dynamic secrets in Vault with ENV on k8s. If you have any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an environment variable to inject a secret, you will need to recreate the pod whenever the secret changes (as you've found), because the environment variable is only generated at startup of the pod - it is not possible to change an environment variable for a running application. If you want your application to support credentials that change while it is running, you will need to add support for that to your application I'm afraid (and change from using an env var to reading the details from the file when required).